# modified batch find replace and use tab

Tags: batch-file

I search to change something.

I got a find and replace here : http://www.dostips.com/?t=Batch.FindAndReplace

I want to replace comma with tabulation. But my replace of %1 %2 %3 is wrong.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
SETLOCAL DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

@echo off set OldStr=,
@echo off set NewStr=\t
@echo off set FilePath=%UserProfile%\Desktop\information.csv

if "%OldStr%"=="" findstr "^::" "%~f0"&GOTO:EOF
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=]" %%A in ('"type %FilePath%|find /n /v """') do (
    set "line=%%B"
    if defined line (
        call set "line=echo.%%line:%OldStr%=%NewStr%"
        for /f "delims=" %%X in ('"echo."%%line%%""') do %%~X
    ) ELSE echo.
)
```

I'm not sure the \t working.

I try to change the command because I need 1 batch file to do all I want.

---

Original

```
@echo off
REM -- Prepare the Command Processor --
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
SETLOCAL DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

::BatchSubstitude - parses a File line by line and replaces a substring"
::syntax: BatchSubstitude.bat OldStr NewStr File
::          OldStr [in] - string to be replaced
::          NewStr [in] - string to replace with
::          File   [in] - file to be parsed
:$changed 20100115
:$source http://www.dostips.com
if "%~1"=="" findstr "^::" "%~f0"&GOTO:EOF
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=]" %%A in ('"type %3|find /n /v """') do (
    set "line=%%B"
    if defined line (
        call set "line=echo.%%line:%~1=%~2%%"
        for /f "delims=" %%X in ('"echo."%%line%%""') do %%~X
    ) ELSE echo.
)
```

I want to use this script on my own batch file. So I need to change the parameters by a var.

Comment: I can see there are many potential areas of error in your code. You should begin trying to understand, line by line, what the code is doing, checking if that is what you want to do or not, and come back with more concrete questions. We will be happy to help you.

Comment: I edit my post. I'm begginer in batch, I can understand globaly what it done, but why the ~ something theres so much %. I ask because there's people who already know how to do the change.

Comment: Read about Environment variable substitution in Set /?

Answer (score 1):

change , in \t

```
@echo off

REM -- Prepare the Command Processor --
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
SETLOCAL DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

if /I "%~1"=="/h" goto:help
if "%UserProfile%\Desktop\%ComputerName%.csv"=="" goto:help

if ","=="" findstr "^::" "%~f0"&goto:help
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=]" %%A in ('"type %UserProfile%\Desktop\%ComputerName%.csv|find /n /v """') do (
    set "line=%%B"
    if defined line (
        call set "line=echo.%%line:,=   %%"
        for /f "delims=" %%X in ('"echo."%%line%%""')  do %%~X >> %UserProfile%\Desktop\%ComputerName%.csv_new
    ) ELSE echo.
)
move /Y %UserProfile%\Desktop\%ComputerName%.csv_new %UserProfile%\Desktop\%ComputerName%.csv >nul
```